# How to get consistent white balance across a group of JPEG images using darktable?

Tags: white-balance, darktable, raw-vs-jpeg

I have about 7 photos, showing of the same place. Walls are white. Each picture has a different white tone for the walls and I would like to adjust all the walls, preferably automatically!
How can I do so? I know how to copy/paste a white balance but all my pictures doesn’t have the same color defaults. Thanks in advance for your help!
[Example of 4 original photos details](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1472717098.png)

Comment: Copy and pasting the white balance should do the trick in darktable (I have used this before for the same purpose). Can you post some examples of the inconsistency you see. Are you certain that all the walls are lit with the same colour light?

Comment: Just to clarify: you *are* talking about RAW files, not JPEGs, right?

Comment: @HarryHarrison Yes the walls have the same color originally, but the color of those depends on the photo angle. I edited my original post with an example.

Comment: @junkyardsparkle I have JPEGs for this project

Comment: It sounds odd that the color temperature would change under change of the photo angle. Can you please include the images?

Comment: @null Some walls are in front of the window light, some doesn’t. It explains the change of temperature.

Comment: @null: The camera probably used a slightly different auto-white-balance for each shot based on shifting light balance, and since they're JPEGs, the WB is baked into the files, unfortunately.

Comment: What to take away from this: use RAW by default and a fixed white balance setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're editing JPEG files, you'll need to correct the white balance for each individually. This is because JPEGs are a *product* of the (apparently varying) camera-selected white balance, instead of just having it *included as information* as with a RAW file (which can simply be discarded when applying the same WB to a batch of images).

You can select "spot" in the preset list of the darktable white balance module to do this automatically. You may want to adjust the sampled area (by default almost the whole image) to include only an area that should actually be white *in each picture*. You may want to increase the exposure slightly after doing this, since a decrease in exposure in any RGB channel doesn't usually look good with JPEGs (they don't have the extra information in bright areas that RAW files do).